# Where can I get a X509 certificate with my email address embedded and nonRepudiation and digitalSignature bits set?

Tags: security, certificate, digital-signature, x509, client-certificate

I would like to buy a X.509 certificate for user authentication not for SSL. The certificate should have my email address in it and should have 2 bits set in KeyUsage extension:

```
nonRepudiation
digitalSignature
```

There are hundreds of places on the web who sell SSL certificates. Can someone recommend where can I buy a certificate with the above requirements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an “S/MIME email certificate”. There are still a few public CAs around that issue them. I don’t know anyone’s policies about the exact Key Usage statements they put on them, so I’m not sure about the non repudiation bit, but the rest should be standard for an email cert.